# Has Batman ever been portrayed as being afraid of heights before?

Tags: dc, batman, the-batman

In *The Batman* (2022), Batman is afraid of heights:

[image: Batman backing away from the edge of a building, clearly afraid]

Has Batman ever been portrayed as being afraid of heights before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the episode *[Nothing to Fear](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Nothing_to_Fear)* from *[Batman: The Animated Series (1992)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3A_The_Animated_Series)*, Batman was intoxicated by the Scarecrow's fear toxin, because of which Batman has a lot hallucinations which cause him to panic.

Among all the things that scare him, there is a point during the episode in which he is on a dirigible, and the animation makes it clear that he's also scared of heights (he looks down towards the ground and there's a kind of panicking zoom-in/zoom-out effect to emphasize on how far he is from the ground):